# Error running composer require pusher/pusher-php-server

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller, lumen

Im getting this error when running composer require pusher/pusher-php-server to install Pusher on Laravel/Lumen

[image]

Can someone hel
This seems to be about the php version but i don't know how to solve it?

**This is my composer.json:**

```
{
"name": "laravel/lumen",
"description": "The Laravel Lumen Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel", "lumen"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": "^7.3|^8.0",
    "laravel/legacy-factories": "^1.1",
    "laravel/lumen-framework": "^8.0",
    "laravel/tinker": "^2.6",
    "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^6.1",
    "vluzrmos/tinker": "^1.4",
    "wn/lumen-generators": "^1.3"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fakerphp/faker": "^1.9.1",
    "mockery/mockery": "^1.3.1",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "^9.3"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/",
        "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
        "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
    }
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist",
    "sort-packages": true,
    "optimize-autoloader": true
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide the contents of your composer.json file? The problem looks to be with vluzrmos/tinker instead of pusher/pusher-php-server

Comment: The problem lies in the difference between your installed PHP version (`8.0.2`) and the PHP version which is required by one or more packages of your project. For example, if a package installed with Composer requires the following PHP version: `"require": { "php": "^7.1.3" }`, then you must have installed only one of the PHP versions found in the version range between `7.1.3` (including `7.1.3`) and `8.0.0` (excluding `8.0.0`). In your case, your PHP version `8.0.2` would exceed the upper range limit (`8.0.0`) of the package. Therefore, the error.

Comment: Read [Writing Version Constraints](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#writing-version-constraints) and, especially, [Caret Version Range](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret-version-range-).

Comment: There is my composer.json. Can i go back to an older php version and the project remains intact?

Comment: You shouldn't need to install a smaller PHP version. Wait with this option... Now, the package [vluzrmos/lumen-tinker](https://packagist.org/packages/vluzrmos/tinker) is abandoned. In the link, there's the advice to use the _"the laravel/tinker package instead"_. You already defined it in the file _"composer.json"_. So, just remove the entry `"vluzrmos/tinker": "^1.4",` from _"composer.json"_ and execute the command `composer update` again. Then tell us the results.

Comment: @dakis I did that and im getting this error. 
- fzaninotto/faker v1.9.2.x-dev requires php ^5.3.3 || ^7.0 -> your PHP version (8.0.2) does not satisfy that requirement.

Comment: **1)** Remove this line: `"prefer-stable": true,`. **2)** Change the line `"minimum-stability": "dev",` to `"minimum-stability": "stable",`. **3)** Upgrade Composer to version 2. [Here is how](https://mikemadison.net/blog/2020/10/14/how-and-why-to-update-to-composer-2). In short, just use the command `composer self-update`. **4)** Remove the folder _"vendor"_ and the file _"composer.lock"_ completely. Reinstall the composer packages used by your project with the commands: `composer clear-cache` followed by `composer update`. A folder _"vendor"_ and a file _"composer.lock"_ will be recreated.

Answer (score 1):

If you use php7.3

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-curl
```

If you use php7.3

```
sudo apt-get install php7.3-curl
```

If you use php7.4

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-curl
```

then you install pusher again

```
composer require pusher/pusher-php-server
```